# Phone app for software design, specifically the flow and general logic

Tags: software-development, iphone-app, google-apps

So I am honestly been struggling to find any sort of phone application that will do what my title describes above. I'm trying to find a way to develop generic software and phone application logic and flow through a mobile device. Trying to do things like have arrows or lines or some way of showing how each page connects to the next. I'm not looking to necessarily fully develop the application or software on my phone. However, I would like to get up to being able to do images of what I think it should look like along with the generic logic regarding if you press this button then it goes to this screen or if you press this button these are the things that it checks before going to the next screen or window or whatever. Basically almost everything up until the actual true physical code of the software or application.

So what is out there? Every phrase of searching I do I get things talking about apps discussing coding and teaching it or other things other than what I am looking for.

Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have part of the key in your reference to searching, although it's apparently the wrong shape key. What you describe sounds very much like flowcharting, a skill taught in early programming courses (80's!).

I used search term "flowchart app iOS" in The Google and found a compilation site, but that was mostly too-brief summaries of a few different programs.

Having had a bit of flowcharting experience behind me, I selected one other link for a promising candidate, called [Lucidchart](https://www.lucidchart.com/pages/flowchart-for-iphone) for the iPhone. The site also references desktop-grade computer applications if you desire dual capability.

The app appears to cover the standard programming flowchart symbols, but also encompasses workflow in general, including network organization and simple work processes. Let's not forget the always-popular Venn diagrams, a popular feature in many math and logic classes, although not specifically referenced here.

A search for "flowchart app android" resulted in an equivalently large selection, although my first checks showed apps with less sophistication than those available for the iOS world.

[image: flowchart app ios]

Comment: Sorry for just now getting back to you. I have gone ahead and downloaded LucidChart and so far it has worked really really well. However, one piece I feel it is missing is documentation regarding what you are wanting to have in your software/app. What I mean by this is say I am building a shopping list app. I would want somewhere I could type in all of the pages I want, then the details of each of those pages and possibly details of those details. Now, the dream would be that each one of those items becomes a main section on the flowchart and links would go to the details and such or something

Comment: And yes, that second thing might be a little much, but just a personal idea. I understand I can use pen and paper, but then if I miss sections and such I have to rework the whole paper. Anyways, I could just be literally wanting something so specific that there just might not be anything out there that I want and will have to just use what is out there and combine it with other things. :)